# Black and Decker drill bit set with Kobalt drill?

Tags: drill

How universal are drills and bit sets? Can I mix and match bit brands with drill brands? For example, would a [Black and Decker bit set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0033BLWPA) work with a [Kobalt drill](http://www.kobalttools.com/products/power-tools/cordless/item/kobalt-20-volt-max-1-2-in-cordless-drill.html?category_id=8)? Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm quite new to all of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're universal. That'll work just fine. Drills have chucks with three jaws that clamp down on whatever you stick in them, so they can use round-shank bits and hex bits too.

Comment: One point to watch out for: That particular drill has a 1/2-inch chuck, which will handle the shafts of most drill bits you're likely to want to use. Some (typically lower-powered) drills have chucks which will only accept bits with a shank of 3/8" or less, which will still handle the most common cases; a few may even top out at 1/4". If you have particular applications in mind, make sure the drill you want to use will take those bits -- or go for 1/2" for maximum flexibility.